# Transforming expressions into GNU MPL syntax

Tags: c, gmp, arbitrary-precision

I have to calculate a bunch of C expressions like this:

```
(-2*a*Power(E,-(((a + b)*x3)/n3) + (b*x2 + a*x3)/n3)*Power(n3,2))/Power(a - b,3) + (2*a*Power(E,-(((a + b)*x3)/n3) + (a*x2 + b*x3)/n3)*Power(n3,2))/Power(a - b,3)
```

This is part of a C implementation. Now I'd like to use the GNU multiple precision library. I know it has it's own special syntax. I was now thinking what would be the best way to calculate my expressions ? Is there any kind of "parser" to transform entire expressions ? I haven't found anything like that. I was also thinking of writing a script to split my expressions into atomic operations and then transform it into MP syntax, but wanted to see if there's something else first. To be honest, formulas are very long, and transforming it into single operations in GNU MP would create an extremely long source code. I got a bit stuck here unfortunately. I've worked with small examples, but don't know what to do with the long expressions.

thanks a lot.

Comment: Is using C++ an option? The GMP C++ bindings make this a lot easier since C++ has operator overloading: http://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Interface-General.html

Comment: that's a nice idea. however I can't really switch to C++ since the calculations are just a tiny part in a pretty big C program

Comment: Is it a tiny part that is easy to isolate though? If so, you could just stick the calculations in an extra C++ source file, provide an interface that is cleanly accessible from C (not a problem, you can pass the GMP C structs and return them), and link both together. Although without knowing more about the project it's hard to say whether the extra complexity added to the build process etc really offsets not having to rewrite the algebraic expressions...

Comment: well, the actual calculations need to be done millions of times. however, they are just a small part of the whole program, but I'm a bit concerned about any loss in computational speed if passing between C and C++. every second counts. but good point, I'll think about that